# What does `@something` stand for in `rvm use 2.0.0@something`?

Tags: ruby, rvm, gemset

As the title says, can't find any documentation on what `@something` does in `rvm use 2.0.0@something`?

Comment: i agree rvm can be confusing at times , so giving benefit of doubt upvoting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RVM is the Ruby Version Manager and its website is here: https://rvm.io/

The command `rvm use 2.0.0@something` tells RVM to change the setup of your current shell (terminal) so that you are using ruby 2.0.0.  It also says to use the gemset named `something`.  Gemsets are a feature of RVM that let you segregate your Ruby gems into different sets.

More information about gemsets is here: https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics

Comment: Thanks David. Know and love using RVM, but didn't find the info about using specific gemsets.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are working on three parallel projects: one uses Ruby 1.9.3 and two use Ruby 2.0.0. Lets say:

- Project A: Ruby 1.9.3
- Project B: Ruby 2.0.0
- Project C: Ruby 2.0.0

When you are working on Project A, you can just say `rvm use 1.9.3`, and it will set your current Ruby version to 1.9.3.

Problems arise when you are working on Project B or C, and they are using different versions of the same gem (lets say Project B uses `httparty 1.0`, and project C uses `httparty 2.0`).

In this case, rvm not only allows you to use different rubies by using `rvm use`, but also allows you to use different sets of gems with each Ruby (called `gemsets`).

So you can just say(When on project B): rvm use 2.0.0@project_b_gemset (and this will install all the gems required for project B as a different set)

When you are on project C, you can just say `rvm use 2.0.0@project_c_gemset`, and this will install all of the gems required for project C as a different set. And hence you can use different sets of gems with the same Ruby version.

Summing up:

```
rvm use ruby_version@gemset_version:
```

`ruby_version` allows segregation on the basis of Ruby versions and `gemset_version` allows you to do further segregation inside the same version of Ruby.